# Compilation Error: libDAI-0.3.2 in Ubuntu 14.04 with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, makefile, g++, ubuntu-14.04, g++-4.7

I am trying to install **libDAI-0.3.2** in Ubuntu 14.04.  I need to use it with MATLAB.

I made following changes :

1. In Makefile.conf:

   CC=g++-4.7

   MEXFLAGS:=CXX=#$(CC) CXXFLAGS#'$(CCFLAGS)'
2. In  Makefile.ALL: `WITH_MATLAB=true`
3. Since  default compiler in Ubuntu 14.04 is gcc 4.8.4, I installed gcc-4.7 and g++4.7.

Still I get the following compilation error:

```
    libDAI-0.3.2$ make
    /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/mex -Iinclude CXX= -largeArrayDims  -lgmpxx -lgmp  -output matlab/dai.mexa64 src/matlab/dai.cpp src/matlab/matlab.cpp src/graph.cpp src/dag.cpp src/bipgraph.cpp src/varset.cpp src/daialg.cpp src/alldai.cpp src/clustergraph.cpp src/factor.cpp src/factorgraph.cpp src/properties.cpp src/regiongraph.cpp src/cobwebgraph.cpp src/util.cpp src/weightedgraph.cpp src/exceptions.cpp src/exactinf.cpp src/evidence.cpp src/emalg.cpp src/io.cpp src/bp.cpp src/fbp.cpp src/trwbp.cpp src/mf.cpp src/hak.cpp src/lc.cpp src/treeep.cpp src/jtree.cpp src/mr.cpp src/gibbs.cpp src/bbp.cpp src/cbp.cpp src/bp_dual.cpp src/decmap.cpp src/glc.cpp
    Building with 'g++'.
     /tmp/mex_11282758003780_5023: -c: not found

make: *** [matlab/dai.mexa64] Error 255
```

what does this mean? Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks & Regards,
Swagatika

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```
MEXFLAGS:=CXX=#$(CC) CXXFLAGS#'$(CCFLAGS)'
```

with

```
MEXFLAGS:=CXX=$(CC) CXXFLAGS='$(CCFLAGS)'
```

Comment: Thanks! just the command change helped :) MEXFLAGS:=CXX=$(CC) CXXFLAGS='$(CCFLAGS)'

Comment: You are welcome, In that case I edit the answer accordingly..Happy programming :)

Answer (score 1):

MEXFLAGS:=CXX=$(CC) CXXFLAGS='$(CCFLAGS)' replace this